# Unity countdown 7 days and reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I am trying to make a realtime 7 days countdown in Unity C# but am not sure how to do so?

I want to be able to get HH:MM:SS

So far I have this:

```
public UILabel timerLabel;

public float myTimer = 3000.0f;

void Update () {    
    if(myTimer>0) {
        myTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        //int days = Mathf.FloorToInt(myTimer / 60F);
        //int hours = Mathf.FloorToInt(myTimer / 60F);
        int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(myTimer / 60F);
        int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(myTimer - minutes * 60);

        string niceTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", minutes, minutes, seconds);

        timerLabel.text= niceTime;
    }   

}
```

I would like to, when a user opens the game, get the current time (not device time but some kind of world time) and be able to set a standard time when it should reset, lets say each sunday @ midnight.

Is this possible, and if yes... how?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

####### EDIT

OK, have tried Chris Mills-Price's Solution like this:

```
public UILabel timerLabel;

DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

void Start(){
    worldTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    startTime = Convert.ToDateTime("08/31/2015 00:00:01");
    endTime = startTime.AddDays(7);
}

void Update () {    
    TimeSpan timeRemaining = endTime-startTime;

    int hours   = (int) timeRemaining.TotalHours; // truncate partial hours
    int minutes = timeRemaining.Minutes;
    int seconds = timeRemaining.Seconds;

    string niceTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);

    timerLabel.text= niceTime;
}
```

I can't make it do What i want. What i get is only this from timeRemaining: 7.00:00:00

My starttime seems to be OK and endTime also. What am I missing?

Hoping for help :-)

Comment: [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Is that device independent?

Comment: @Mansa, read the link. UTC = Coordinated Universal Time. So yes.

Comment: Do you want `totalTimeSpentInWorld` or a `totalRealWorldTimeSinceStartedPlaying` sort of thing?

Comment: I want to make a counter that always count down 7 days. From sunday to sunday.

Answer (score 0):

As theB suggested, `DateTime.UtcNow` is likely what you want.

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also offers many methods to help do Date arithmetic, making this a pretty straightforward task.

In your case, assuming you had:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

you could then compute the value a week later with:

```
DateTime endTime = startTime.AddDays(7);
```

To compute your HH:MM:SS values, subtract one from the other to get a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the `TimeSpan`TotalHours/Minutes/Seconds properties.

```
TimeSpan timeRemaining = endTime-startTime;

int hours   = (int) timeRemaining.TotalHours; // truncate partial hours
int minutes = timeRemaining.Minutes;
int seconds = timeRemaining.Seconds;
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as described in my original post after EDIT but am unsuccessfully. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you're always going to get 7 days because in your code, startTime is a fixed date, and endTime is a fixed date. Try calculating worldTime at the start of Update() as well, then calculate timeRemaining as endTime-worldTime.

Comment: Ahhh, Perfekt :-) Did the job (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `starttime`.

```
TimeSpan timeRemaining = endTime-DateTime.UtcNow;
```